# Basic understanding of Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm new to woocommerce and have a question for the basic understanding of the shop pages.

When I create a woocommerce shop, woocommerce gives me:

- /shop page - the main page which displays all my products
- /product-category - the pages which show my products in specific

  categories
- /product - the page who shows me the product

Is there a benefit to use this pages instead of just creating a wordpress site with shortcodes with the products i wich to show?

So do I have to use the woocommerce pages or is it ok to just build a shop with wordpress and shortcodes?

Comment: no advantage whatsoever. those pages are just starter templates, so when you install the plugin you are ready to sell things. It's just like buying a car, where you can change the default tires if you want.

Comment: @Reigel - so if I decides not to use the pre build pages, how can I disable them. Because, if I don't use them, I can still go to the /product-category url and see the page. But I dont want that, because I have build it with shortcodes instead.

Comment: `/product-category` is not directly woocommerce but a WordPress thing. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy > rewrite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woo commerce gives this pages to start with, so that if any one installs the plugin he/she is ready to go. Additionally, if you want to have your own structure or pages you can achieve that as well. For that you have to override Woo commerce template structures, for more info you can visit official Woo commerce page https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

So, its totally up to developer which way he/she likes. If he/she is happy with default Woo commerce pages, he/she can style as want and ready to lounge his/her shop. But, if he/she wants full different structure (as his/her own) he/she can override default templates with own templates and that's it. Hope that makes sense by now.

Comment: so if I decides not to use the pre build pages, how can I disable them. Because, if I don't use them, I can still go to the /product-category url and see the page. But I dont want that, because I have build it with shortcodes instead.

Comment: to select your own pages created by shortcodes you can go to WordPress Dashboard, Woo Commerce > settings then click on Products tab button, then click on display link and you are ready to select your desired pages to show products.

Answer (score -1):

Those pages are just templates provided by WooCommerce so that the user can start selling. You can customize those pages or use them.